# At what time does the boarding gate close when flying with LATAM airline between Airport Mataveri (IPC) and Santiago International Airport (SCL)?

Tags: airports, chile, santiago-de-chile, easter-island, latam

At what time does the boarding gate close when flying with LATAM airline between Airport Mataveri (IPC) and Santiago International Airport (SCL)?

On https://helpdesk.latam.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001436968-When-can-I-check-in-for-my-flight- ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20191219075715/http://web.archive.org/screenshot/https://helpdesk.latam.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001436968-When-can-I-check-in-for-my-flight-)) I read:

> If your flight is domestic, you can Check-in between 48 hours and 60 minutes before your flight departure time.
>
> If your flight is international, you can Check-in between 48 hours and 75 minutes before your flight departure time.

But it doesn't specify when the gate is closed, and I don't know if flying between Airport Mataveri (IPC) and Santiago International Airport (SCL) counts as domestic or international.

Answer (score 2):

Gate cutoff times do vary from flight to flight and from airline to airline. For most airlines it's 15-20 minutes but can be substantially longer of there is "special factor" involved. These could be: extra doc/visa check at the gate, security at the gate, bus instead of a jet bridge etc. These factors are hard to predict and can vary even for the same flight.

Most airlines however, will show it on your boarding pass, so you should be able to find out when you check in.

Comment: Thanks, I would prefer to know the gate closing time before checking in to be able to organize my schedule ahead of time

Comment: Allow an hour and you will most likely be right. (If it happens to be 30 or even 15 minutes, you will just have a little more time for a coffee or a bit of reading.)

Comment: @Willeke thanks, I prefer to spend more time outside the airport :)